# About First and second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

Define $\displaystyle f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}e^{-t^2}\mathrm{d}t$.

Evaluate $\displaystyle\int f(x)~\mathrm{d}x$. The final answer may involve $f(x)$. I know about $\displaystyle f'(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f(x)=e^{-x^2}$, after that I can't solve it. Could you give me some hint for next step.

Comment: From what I know, this function looks nonintegrable. Reference: http://www-math.mit.edu/~djk/18_01/chapter25/section05.html

Comment: I'd guess they want you to use integration by parts.

Comment: @littleO I am pretty sure that the function is nonintegrable.

Comment: @jadenlee It is true that the function $e^{-t^2}$ has no elementary antiderivative. But, the instructions say that the answer can be written in terms of $f(x)$.

Comment: @littleO Then, I guess integration by parts with 1 and $f(x)$ seems like it would work

Comment: The [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Comment: Yeah, integration by parts with 1 and $f(x)$ does work. I just solved it.

Comment: Thanks guys, I just solved it by using integration by parts.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Use integration by parts on the integral: $$\int 1\cdot f(x) dx$$ with $dv=1$ and $u=f(x)$

Integration by parts: $$\int u \ dv = uv - \int v \ du$$